# Calculating the Chi-square CDF in C

Tags: c, chi-squared

I'm very new to coding in C, and I'm working on calculating the CDF for a chi-square distribution given a value and the degrees of freedom. Is there a function or a library that does this or will I need to write this code myself?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am right you can use the GNU Scientific Library. Look for the function `gsl_ran_chisq`, which returns a random value from a Chi-square distribution provided a number of degrees of freedom.

You can check the C functions related to chi-square and many other distributions on this  [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Chi_002dsquared-Distribution.html). Simply install the library. Link to the lib's home page can also be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/).

I hope I have helped.

Comment: I think this is very helpful. However, I do not fully understand how to download and utilize something with a .gz file extension. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, so here is the thing. Files with the .tar.gz extensions are no different from zip files in many aspects. But they are usually used in linux/POSIX systems.

Comment: I assume you are using Windows, so installing manually a library from GNU may not be something really easy. However, GNU SL does have support from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: Which is a tool that "transforms" your system environment into something close to a POSIX system. I am not really sure if that is what you want though, since it involves much more work.

Comment: I actually do have access to a linux machine, and I was able to download and extract the .gz file. However when I try to write a program using the #include<gsl/gsl_cdf.h> header I get a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: I tried moving gsl-1.16 into /usr/local/lib, but it still return the same error message.

Comment: Oh, ok! That should make things easier. Instead of manually going in the directory 'usr/local/lib', try going to the folder via terminal and type 'make install'.

This way, the installation is done automatically. GSL is a big library, with a lot of files. It is much easier to let it be done automatically.

Comment: This worked. Hover, I again, ran into another problem. When I run my program, it says I have an "undefined reference to 'gsl-cdf-chisq-P'(the function I am trying to use)." Any ideas? Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Maybe you have typed the name of the function wrong. According to [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Chi_002dsquared-Distribution.html) the function that you may be referring is written with underscores (`_`), instead of using (`-`). So it might be that the function is actually named `gsl_cdf_chisq_P` instead of `gsl-cdf-chisq-P`

Comment: Just another thing. If the answer solved your problem, you might as well accept it and close the question.